# JS animate - something wrong with my syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you pls let me know what is wrong with my syntax?

This works:

```
$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, "slow");
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, {duration: "3000", easing:"easein"});
```

Thanks;

Comment: `$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, "slow";` should be `$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, "slow");` so not sure why thats working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easing is not a default option swing and linear are.

```
$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, {duration: "3000", easing:"swing"});
```

You can use a plugin to get more easing options:
https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing

Comment: Probably he uses jQuery UI plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Your second parameter shouldn't be an object, but 2 separate parameters as shown in the [jQuery animate docs](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, "3000", "easein");
```

Answer (score 1):

$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, 3000, "easein"});

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have both jQuery AND jQueryUI as easing comes from jQueryUI.

http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Then try this:

```
$("#grow").animate({height: "500px"}, {duration: 3000, easing: "easeInQuad"});
```